# Angular service becomes undefined in subsequent calls

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have a service that works fine on ngOnInit, but when I set a timer and invoke it later, it becomes undefined for some reason.

Edit: this is my constructor:

```
constructor(private service: SomeService) { }
```

I tried to create a property private service and set it like this in the constructor:

```
 this.service = service
```

But that still did not solve the issue. I thought by doing it this way, I would keep a reference to the static instance of SomeService.

And I invoke it thus:

```
setTimeout(this.getData, 5000)

getData(): void {
    // Some HTTP call
}
```

Comment: What is needed is the fragment of the code where you "set a timer and invoke it later".

Comment: Added. Please let me know if the edit's not sufficient.

Comment: @Latcie as mbojko said you do not have a right context in callback function.
I believe that `setTimeout(this.getData.bind(this), 5000)` or `setTimeout(() => this.getData(), 5000)` should solve your issue.

Comment: That's done it. Thank you for both your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct `this` context in `ngOnInit`, but lose it in the subsequent calls.

It would be nice if you provided the code, though, it's difficult to provide the correct solution without it. Regardless, `this` is the reason.

Comment: That's actually where I was heading. Edited my original post.